# How to calculate percent of each user in single query?

Tags: mysql

I make a query, that show each user answer amount of question for each department and correct and incorrect percent of each user when they answer question for that department.

So, I try a query like this,

```
SELECT  d.department_id, d.department_name as department, 
        a.username, COUNT(a.username)total,
        (  (COUNT(r.is_correct)*100) / 
              (   SELECT COUNT(a.username) total
                  FROM qa_report r
                  LEFT JOIN tbl_user a ON (r.user_id = a.admin_id)
                  LEFT JOIN department d on (a.department_id = d.department_id)
                  WHERE d.department_name = 'Dept1' AND is_correct='yes'
              )
        ) as correct_percent
FROM qa_report r
LEFT JOIN tbl_user a ON (r.user_id = a.admin_id)
LEFT JOIN department d on (a.department_id = d.department_id)
WHERE d.department_name = 'Dept1'
GROUP BY a.username
```

This is the result,

[image: query result]

`total` column is the amount of question's answer that user answer for that department.

In this `total`, correct and incorrect answer are mixing.

but the `correct_percent` column is still wrong when I try to calculate correct/incorrect percent of each department.

The problem is at this line,

```
(  (COUNT(r.is_correct)*100) / 
          (   SELECT COUNT(a.username) total
              FROM qa_report r
              LEFT JOIN tbl_user a ON (r.user_id = a.admin_id)
              LEFT JOIN department d on (a.department_id = d.department_id)
              WHERE d.department_name = 'Dept1' AND is_correct='yes'
          )
    ) as correct_percent
```

I need to get the correct percent of each user at that place like this,

`(correct percent of answer*100)/total question that user answer
eg. John => total: 10, correct 5, incorrect 5, correct %=50%`

I very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: post all the related table structure please.

Comment: Thank you, now I can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve this problem now. I was wrong when I try to calculate percentage.
Here is the query that work,

```
SELECT  d.department_id, d.department_name as department, 
    a.username, COUNT(a.username)total,
    (  (COUNT(CASE WHEN r.is_correct='yes' THEN 1 END)*100) / ( COUNT(a.username)) ) as correct_percent,
    (  (COUNT(CASE WHEN r.is_correct='no' THEN 1 END)*100) / ( COUNT(a.username)) ) as incorrect_percent
FROM qa_report r
LEFT JOIN tbl_user a ON (r.user_id = a.admin_id)
LEFT JOIN department d on (a.department_id = d.department_id)
WHERE d.department_name = 'Dept1'
GROUP BY a.username
```

Hope this help for someone.